# Constantly check if a condition is true - Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am making an android application with Android Studio in Java. My goal is to be able to constantly check if a condition is true, for example if a variable is true it must take certain action. How can I always check this variable and not just once when starting the program?

Comment: you can use observer pattern

Comment: you can create a new thread and then use polling technique (there are many better alternatives, this is the simplest) in that thread to continuously check for a variable to be true.  You can also use the observer pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: There's many different ways to "always" check something like that and which one is most appropriate to you really depends on the specifics. In a game, that might look very different from a "normal" application ... can you give some background on what your app is and what the *specific* condition is you want to always check?

Comment: (Obser pattern) Some objects register change listeners, which get signaled by the object on any change. This is optimal. You register a listener that on an overriden change does something. The other way is a timer that periodically calls your overriden method.

Comment: Look into how to create schedulers. Scheduled tasks run in the background thread at specific intervals. (Cron Jobs, Quartz Scheduler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use code snippets like give below and put them into a **thread** which always run parallel to your main code

```
while(true)
{
  if(_val)  //_val is your boolean variable
  {
      // your logic
  }
  Thread.sleep(100);

}
```

Or an event can be raised on the click of that particular control which checks value of `_val` and performs actions

Method 2:
Use observable pattern:
You can wrap a boolean in a class which you can listen for changes on.

```
class ObservableBoolean {
    
    // "CopyOnWrite" to avoid concurrent modification exceptions in loop below.
    private final List<ChangeListener> listeners =
            new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ChangeListener>();
    
    private boolean value;
    
    public boolean getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public synchronized void setValue(boolean b) {
        value = b;
        for (ChangeListener cl : listeners)
            cl.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
    }
    
    public synchronized void addChangeListener(ChangeListener cl) {
        listeners.add(cl);
    }
    
    public synchronized void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener cl) {
        listeners.remove(cl);
    }
}
```

Then simply do:

```
ObservableBoolean b = new ObservableBoolean();

//...

// Start the "period of time":
b.addChangeListener(iWantToBeNotifiedOfChanges);

// ...

// End the "period of time":
b.removeChangeListener(iWantToBeNotifiedOfChanges);
```

This is actually a simple case of the MVC pattern (and the observer pattern). The model in this case is the ObservableBoolean and the view would be the "view" that wants to be notified of the changes.

You could also write your own `ChangeListener` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) for this purpose. Below is the sample usage of how you can do it.

```
MutableLiveData<boolean> boolToObserve = new MutableLiveData<boolean>();
// onCreate of Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    booltoObserve.observe(this, new Observer<boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final boolean newValue) {
            MyActivity.this.valueChanged(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you do not need to take care of checking the value again and again. As soon as this value is changed from anywhere, your method will be called. Hope this helps.

EDIT:
You can change this value this way from you logic:

```
boolToObserve.setValue(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` and `java.util.TimerTask` is a possible solution:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
 new TimerTask(){
 public void run(){ System.out.println("hello"); //make your call here
    }
},
0,      // run first occurrence immediatetly
3000)); //runs every three seconds
```

Comment: While this does somewhat answer the question, there are holes in this answer. Many things can happen in the 3000ms. You can reduce that 3000ms, but I feel an appropriate solution would be to trigger an event when that value is updated to take immediate action.